# NetLogo: draw pcolor on top of gis:fill

Tags: gis, netlogo

Is it possible to have patches' `pcolor` to display on top of 'pictorial' GIS drawn using `gis:fill`?

Comment: The drawing layer always appears over the patches, never under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seth's right. If you want a (very janky) workaround, you can get the patches whose color you want to display to sprout a square turtle to stamp the patchess colors on top of current drawings. Because it's a drawing layer, there's not much you can do with it afterwards, but if it's just for a quick display this *may* work for what you need:

```
to dubious-workaround
  ask patches with [ pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0 ] [
    sprout 1 [
      set color pcolor
      set heading 0
      set size 1.25 
      set shape "square"
      stamp 
      die
    ]
  ]
end
```